# Can I view the downvotes cast by another user in the user's profile page?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, down-votes

If I enter someone's profile, and go to Activity>reputation. I can see the questions where that person received a downvote as a "-2", but can I see the questions that he/she cast a downvote (as a "-1")?

Comment: No, that would compromise anonymity of the voters, risking that they are going to be persuaded to change their vote.

Comment: I would hope this isn't possible. Votes should be anonymous unless you you leave a comment saying that you voted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Voting has been and will always be anonymous as it is the primary way of how quality control works on the SE sites.

This goes even so far that moderators can't see who voted on a post. It needs an SE developer with access to the database to find out who voted on what.